# How to optimize my code for an xarray dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, netcdf, python-xarray

i'm trying to calculate the trend of a large file using xarray module and pymannkendall.

These are the dimensions of my dataset:

```
dimensions:
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (20 currently)
    lon = 3502 ;
    lat = 3724 ;
```

This is the code I'm using to calculate the trend:

```
# Import modules
import xarray as xr
import pymannkendall as mk

# Slope-Trend Function
def calc_slope(ds):
# Slope for Theil-Sen
output_slope = []
for lat in np.arange(len(ds.lat.values)):
    for lon in np.arange(len(ds.lon.values)):
        try:
            slope = mk.hamed_rao_modification_test(ds[:, lat, lon]).slope
        except:
            slope = np.nan  # if nan values exists
        output_slope.append(slope)

output_slope = np.copy(output_slope).reshape(ds.lat.size, ds.lon.size)
return xr.DataArray(output_slope, dims=('lat', 'lon'), coords={
    'lat': ds.lat, 'lon': ds.lon})

### Open Dataset
   
ds = xr.open_dataset('data.nc')

### get variable
ts = ds.ts

### Calculate slope-trend
trend = calc_slope(ts)
```

This code works for small files, but when it comes to large files, the processing time takes many hours or days.

Is there any other possibilities for processing this calculate trend in xarray?

can someone help me? I`d be very grateful.

Comment: What do you mean by "trend"? Please explain your question instead of requiring users to read your code to figure out what you are trying to do

Comment: Trend is a general direction in which something is developing or changing.
In this case I'm calculating the trend of a climatological variable. If this variable is changing (increasing or decreasing) over time
And I would like to know if there is another faster way to do this in python.
Because with the code above, it's taking too long to be processed.

Comment: If retrieving data from the file is a bottleneck, you may want to apply chunking in the time dimension. e.g. `nccopy -c "time/20,longitude/3502,latitude/1" data.nc chunked_data.nc`